# Inserting into list based on items in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists

```
my_list=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I want to insert a new item after the first item in each list based on this list and repeat:

```
num_range=[1,2]
```

I tried using `enumerate()` but of course I run into an `IndexError`

```
for index,i in enumerate(my_list):
        i.insert(1,num_range[index])
```

Expected:

```
my_list=[[1,1,2,3],[4,2,5,6],[7,1,8,9]]
```

Comment: You get an `IndexError` because `my_list` has 3 lists, but `num_range` only has two elements. What do you expect to happen when `num_range` has less elements than there are lists in `my_list`?

Comment: "based on this list and repeat" To be clear: we modify the last element of `my_list` by inserting a `1`, because we ran out of elements in `num_range=[1,2]` and started over at the beginning of `num_range`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes so if ```my_list=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]``` then ```[[1,1,2,3],[4,2,5,6],[7,1,8,9],[10,2,11,12]]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.cycle` to make a generator over `num_range` that wraps back around to the beginning as needed. Then zip this against your original list to perform your insertions.

```
from itertools import cycle
for sub, i in zip(my_list, cycle(num_range)):
    sub.insert(1, i)
```

Output

```
>>> my_list
[[1, 1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 5, 6], [7, 1, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: The sample code I gave works. However, when I tried it on my actual code, it goes in descending order. Eg. ```[[1,2,1,2,3],[4,2,1,5,6],[7,2,1,8,9]]``` I've never worked with ```itertools``` before so I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: @catzen I'm not sure I follow, can you please edit your question with a more complete example demonstrating your input and desired output?

Comment: Strangely, I ended up printing and copying the output of ```my_list```,  ie. ```[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]``` into another variable ie. ```my_list2=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]``` and your code worked. Not sure what was up with the original list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
from itertools import cycle

for a_list, num_to_insert in zip(my_list, cycle(num_range)):
    a_list.insert(1, num_to_insert)
```

Comment: The sample code I gave works. However, when I tried it on my actual code, it goes in descending order. Eg. ```[[1,2,1,2,3],[4,2,1,5,6],[7,2,1,8,9]]``` I've never worked with ```itertools``` before so I'm not sure how it works.